# How can I Assign hidden value of dxlookup(dropdown in devextreme) to a dxtextbox in devextreme Multichannel application?

Tags: knockout.js, devexpress, devextreme

I'm developing a mobile app using devextreme multi channel application. Here I have a lookup (dxloookup) which loads the data from a table and I can choose the value given within displayExpr property.

The problem is I have to get the another field value from the table when dxlookup is chosen.

For example, I have table columns as stateid, statename, statecountry. And I have lookup for state. If I choose statename as TamilNadu, I need to fill a textbox named Country as 'India'. How can I achieve it using devextreme?

I'm using OdataContext as store. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please show what you have done so far. `HTML`  `Knockout Model` . ex. is your `statename` a `dropdown` list controlling by observable Array ?!! so we can help better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I suggest you use [ko.computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to calculate a dxTextBox value and [ko.observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) for a dxLookup value. It allows you to check if the lookup value is changed and then update the textbox value.

```
var VM = {
    lookupOptions: {
        value: ko.observable()
    },
    textBoxOptions: {}
};

VM.textBoxOptions.value = ko.computed(function() {
    var selectedItem = VM.lookupOptions.value();
    // This function will be called when the lookup value is updated
});
```

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rd67gad/) demonstrates this approach in action.

Comment: Got it. Thank you Sergey :)